# Can i detect 32 or 64 bit OS without plugin somehow?

Tags: nsis

now i use the x64.nsh for this, but i can detect it without this plugin?

#### ${If} ${RunningX64}

```
MessageBox MB_OK "running on 64 bit"
File /r ${64BIT_OPENVPN_INSTALL}   
Execwait ${64BIT_OPENVPN_INSTALL}
```

#### ${Else}

```
MessageBox MB_OK "running on 32 bit"
File /r ${32BIT_OPENVPN_INSTALL}
Execwait ${32BIT_OPENVPN_INSTALL}
```

#### ${EndIf}

Comment: You could check for certain folders or registry entries, but I don't find that the most reliable method. As @Seki pointed out already, x64.nsh is only a header. So right, it relies on the System plugin, but what do you actually have against usingp plugins. System plugin is well established and has been part of the official NSIS distribution for years, many years.

Comment: Why is using a plugin a problem?

Answer (score 2):

`x64.nsh` does not implies specific external plugin usage (apart the system plugin): it is just an included file that defines 3 macros based on kernel calls (i.e `kernel32::GetCurrentProcess()` and `kernel32::IsWow64Process()`) through the system plugin, that can be conveniently used with `LogicLib.nsh`

Comment: The x64.nsh implementation is not set in stone, in the future it might be changed to call shlwapi::IsOS or even as a native NSIS instruction but all current versions use IsWow64Process().

Comment: Yes @Anders. My answer was just to tell the OP that no plugin but system is used to check 64bit and about the feasability of inlining the macro code, while there is not much benefit. I have edited my answer to emphasize that point.

Comment: Copy/Paste of x64.nsh is a bad idea, not just because it is pointless work but the x64.nsh from NSISv3 will not work in NSISv2...

Answer (score 1):

There are probably many ways to detect the native bitness by just looking at files and registry keys but there is always the risk that some 32-bit systems have somehow ended up with a SysWOW64 folder in %WinDir% etc.

The `SetRegView` test should be pretty safe but there is a small window where some other app could change the registry at just the wrong time giving you the wrong result.

The correct way to detect this is of course to call the `IsWow64Process` function and the x64.nsh header already does that for you.

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
!if "${NSIS_PTR_SIZE}" > 4
DetailPrint "64-bit NSIS, this must be a 64-bit system"
!endif

${If} ${FileExists} "$WinDir\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll"
    DetailPrint "Probably not a native 32-bit system"
${EndIf}
${If} ${FileExists} "$WinDir\SysNative\kernel32.dll"
    DetailPrint "Probably a 32-bit app on a native 64-bit system (Vista+ only)"
${EndIf}

SetRegView 64
ReadRegStr $6 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "ProgramFilesDir"
SetRegView lastused
SetRegView 32
ReadRegStr $3 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion" "ProgramFilesDir"
SetRegView lastused
${If} $3 != $6
    DetailPrint "Probably a 32-bit app on a native 64-bit system"
${EndIf}

; ReadEnvStr on ProgramW6432 or PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 etc
SectionEnd
```